# How to know if a string belong to another, even counts if skips letters

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a program to check if string is inside of another in any way? I don't mean the `contain` method. Something like:

- string "AgBgC" contains the string "ABC"
- "browndcodw" contains "brown" and "cow".
- However, "browndcodw" **does not** contain "woc", since the letters are not in order

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: I don't even know what to begin with....

Comment: Ok，try to convert string to []char and compare char by char

Comment: Why don't you want to use `String.contains()`?

Comment: @MarsAtomic Because `"AgBgC".contains("ABC")` is `false`, and OP wants a `true` value.

Comment: @Andreas I suppose the negation operator is off limits too, eh? I'm trying to see if this is an X Y problem that's going to lead to some different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, using [`indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-) to search for the next character:

```java
static boolean containsCharsInOrder(String text, String chars) {
    for (int textIdx = -1, charsIdx = 0; charsIdx < chars.length(); charsIdx++)
        if ((textIdx = text.indexOf(chars.charAt(charsIdx), textIdx + 1)) == -1)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(containsCharsInOrder("AgBgC", "ABC"));
System.out.println(containsCharsInOrder("browndcodw", "brown"));
System.out.println(containsCharsInOrder("browndcodw", "cow"));
System.out.println(containsCharsInOrder("browndcodw", "rod"));
System.out.println(containsCharsInOrder("browndcodw", "dog"));
```

*Output*

```
true
true
true
true
false
```

Comment: Are 'idx' different from 'i' or they are the same, but wrote wrong?

Comment: @MingJunFeng Yes, `idx` is different from `i`. Variable `idx` is the index of the last found character in `text`, while `i` is the index of the next character to find in `chars`. I'll rename to clear up any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using linked lists:

```
 public static boolean scramble(String str1, String str2) {
        LinkedList<Character> linkedList = new LinkedList<Character>();
        for(char a: str1.toCharArray()){
            linkedList.add(a);
        }
        for(char a: str2.toCharArray()) {
            if(!linkedList.remove((Character)a)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

essentially if the first list could not remove a character in the second list, it will automatically return false.

Comment: One thing to note here is that order does not matter in this solution so "woc" would also return true!